# chrome.identity.getAuthToken call skipping choosing account and directly asking for permission while implementing OAuth2 google sign in

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I have been trying to implement google sign in using OAuth 2 in my chrome extension. For doing so I am using the chrome identity API. But the problem is that when I load up the extension first everything works fine.

- I click on login, a pop-up opens asking me to choose my google account
- Then I am asked to give the required permissions
- I am logged in.

But then when I log out and try to login again, **the pop-up skips the part where I have to choose my google account, rather it directly skips to the permissions part keeping the same account that I chose the previous time**. Here's the code for login and logout which I am using :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log('listener called')
  console.log(request.message)
  if (request.message === 'get_auth_token') {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
      user_signed_in = true
      console.log('token: ' + token)
    })
  } else if (request.message === 'get_profile') {
    chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo({ accountStatus: 'ANY' }, function (
      user_info,
    ) {
      console.log(user_info)
    })
  } else if (request.message === 'logout_user') {
    revokeToken()
  }
})

function revokeToken() {
  chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false }, function (
    current_token,
  ) {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      // Remove the local cached token
      chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken(
        { token: current_token },
        function () {},
      )

      // Make a request to revoke token in the server
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open(
        'GET',
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + current_token,
      )
      xhr.send()
      console.log(
        'Token revoked and removed from cache. ' +
          'Check chrome://identity-internals to confirm.',
      )
      alert('You are logged out.')
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi Naman. Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue :(